# Which Command(s) in tcolorbox.sty is Undefined?

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, texlive-2023

Part of a styles file for the [tcolorbox LaTeX package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (tcolorbox.sty) is telling me that I have multiple "Undefined control sequence(s)" when I attempt to convert a file to PDF. One example is shown below since they all seem related. I'm not sure which command is the offending one, and haven't found other similar questions about this issue! Can anyone help with this?

The error I get after running $ xelatex filename.tex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__tcobox_set_backslash_removed:Nn ...1\tl_set:Ne 
                                                  #1{\exp_last_unbraced:NV \...
l.2522 \DeclareTotalTCBox{\tcboxverb}
                                     { O{} v }{verbatim,#1}{#2}
```

And I found the two parts of the code, copied here:

```
l.2315 \cs_new:Npn \__tcobox_set_backslash_removed:Nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
    \tl_trim_spaces:N #1
    \tl_set:Ne #1 { \exp_last_unbraced:NV \cs_to_str:N #1 }
  }

l.2522 \DeclareTotalTCBox{\tcboxverb}{ O{} v }{verbatim,#1}{#2}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Update your TeX distribution, which already @Joseph; suggested

Answer (score 2):

The undefined command, as shown by the error, is `\tl_set:Ne`. This suggests you have an older `expl3` than the version of `tcolorbox` you have installed expects. You could try adding

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

before loading `tcolorbox`, but it's quite possible you will get further errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My l3kernel (which I believe includes expl3?) is current. I've also gone ahead and emailed the developer through gitHub (https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/268) and they caught that my LaTeX2e is showing up as 2022-11-01 instead of the current version.

I've tried using the $ tlmgr update --self --all command, and I've downloaded the recent MacTeX (https://www.tug.org/mactex/). I'm not sure what else I can try to get the LaTeX2e updated.

Thank you for your help!