# Old LaTeX Distributions Blocking Current TeX Live 2023 from Being Used?

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, mactex, distributions, texlive-2023

I have been having a series of complications converting a *.tex file to PDF using either Jupyter notebook or `$ xelatex filename.tex`. These issues consistently come up with the tcolorbox package, which requires the most recent l3kernel (2024-01-22) and LaTeX2e. You can find previous troubleshooting attempts at [GitHub Issue #268](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/268) and [StackExchange Inquiry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708183/which-commands-in-tcolorbox-sty-is-undefined).

After various attempts to fix the issue, it seems that the problem is xelatex is using an older TeX distribution to render the PDF instead of the newly installed or updated TeX Live 2023. Specifically, the tcolorbox developer kindly pointed out that the latex error file lists the 2023 l3kernel and 2022 LaTeX2e are being used:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex 2024.1.28)  29 JAN 2024 20:28
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Module 01/Enviroment Test/Jupiter Notebook Enviroment Test Document.tex"
(./Module 01/Enviroment Test/Jupiter Notebook Enviroment Test Document.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
```

So far I have:

- Uninstalled the TinyTex R package, which was blocking use of the TeX Live 2023 distribution and causing a tlmgr package repository verification block on account of an expired key (this issue is now resolved).
- Checked TeX Live Utility, /Library/, and /user/local/texlive to confirm that TeX Live 2023 is fully updated and even removed older distributions.
- Used `$ tlmgr update --self --all` as well as `$ tlmgr update --self latex l3kernel l3backend` and reinstalling [MacTeX 2023](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) to ensure everything used through xelatex would be updated.

At this point, I have no clue where xelatex is pulling these old distributions from or even why it is doing that when I render even the simplest tex files with tcolorbox. Is there a way to force a clean uninstall for all TeX distributions on a Mac computer? Is there a way to set the path for xelatex? What do you recommend I try to fix this issue?

Any guidance with this issue is greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Your log file should say where the files are being read from, so if any are being found in unexpected places, you should check your path setting.

Comment: Hi Barbara, thank you for your reply. It looks like all TeX paths are through TeX Live 2023. I'm not sure if this is right, but it looks like LaTeX2e and L3 programming layer are coming from article.cls and size11.clo in the /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ location. Is there a way to update or change these to the current versions for both? Or is this a limitation of MacTeX?

Comment: What do you get from `kpsewhich --all latex.ltx`? And what do you get from `kpsewhich ‐engine≈xetex ‐‐all xelatex.fmt`? What do get from `tlmgr update --list`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `engine almost equal to xetex`  interesting option.

Comment: @barbarabeeton tex does not log the path to the format file (which is almost certainly what is wrong here) see Ulrike's comment (but with `=` not `≈`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ;-). Typing on a smartphone is hard work and I get it only almost right ;-)

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your replies. @UlrikeFischer,  when I try ```kpsewhich --all latex.ltx``` I get /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
and /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/latex.ltx. When I try ```kpsewhich ‐engine=xetex ‐‐all xelatex.fmt``` I don't get anything (I changed the approx eq. to an equal). Yesterday ```tlmgr update --list``` said there were no more updates needed, and today it listed easybook, llncs, proflycee, pst-solarsystem, tex4ht, and texlive-scripts. I've gone ahead and updated those with ```sudo tlmgr update --all```.

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have one or more packages (not binaries) installed to texmf-local or texmf home? I have done that when experimenting with code, then forgot I had the files there. Local and home files will take precedence over installed files. Also, did you copy any package *sty files to the same directory as your main document? Those take precedence.

Comment: Hi @rallg. I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by texmf-local or -home. In the /usr/local/texlive/2023 folder I see texmf-var, -dist, and -confg subfolders with texmf.cnf and texmfcnf.lua documents. Are those folders located somewhere else?

Comment: The mentioned folders are possibly located somewhere else, but if you used them in the past, you would know that. In any case, navigate to the `texmf-dist` folder, then go one level up. Do you see a `texmf-local` folder there? If so, look inside. It should have no packages unless you put them there. Then go the your home directory, and show hidden folders. Do you see anything with `texmf` in the name? If so, enter it, and look around. There are other possibilities, which can be revealed by asking the `kpathsea` program to show you where it looks for things. It provides help.

Comment: you must have a xelatex format, after all your log-file above used it.  Perhaps you need two dashes on the mac:  `kpsewhich ‐-engine=xetex ‐‐all xelatex.fmt`.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, perhaps this is an indicator of what my systems issue is? I tried your update and got no return. I also looked at the engine command in the tug.org (https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html) site and tried three other commands: ```kpsewhich engine=xetex --all```, ```kpsewhich engine=xetex```, and ```kpsewhich engine=/```. Based on what tug describes the ```engine/``` should do, I thought that would surely return some answers. Actually, none of these commands return anything. This is interesting because using ```xelatex``` produces a PDF. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, scratch my last comment, if you read it. This is a facepalm moment as I forgot the add the two dashes before engine just now. When I use ```kpsewhich --engine=xetex --all xelatex.fmt``` I get /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt. It looks like the command is coming from the expected TeX distribution (TeX Live 2023). I'm not sure why the usage of LaTeX2e and l3kernel are not updated. I have checked the Read Me file for l3kernel, and confirmed the package there is current. I even tried downloading it from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel?lang=en).

Comment: well now you know where the format is. So check its date.  In texmf-var should also be the log-file from the last format creation.

Comment: Not sure exactly which folder in texmf-var you mean, but assuming you mean /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c/xetex the xelatex.log says the same versions discussed above are being used: LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1 and Package: expl3 2023-02-22 L3 programming layer (code). As far as I know, this is not the current version that needs to be used. When I run ```$ tlmgr update --self latex l3kernel l3backend```, as I did above, it says that there were no updates available. Maybe MacTeX 2023 is just behind the PC version?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all of your comments and attempts to help me find whatever shadowing format or conflicting TeX distributions might be blocking the updated l3 programming layer from being used. I just found an answer to whatever that problem was. First, I explored the error associated with the `expl3.sty` file. Specifically, the error was

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-01-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 
! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX)        
(LaTeX)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX)        is dated 2023-02-22, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX)        at least 2024-01-22.
```

This was following the error preamble

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex 2024.1.28)  29 JAN 2024 21:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Module 01/Enviroment Test/tcolorbox Removed.tex"
(./Module 01/Enviroment Test/tcolorbox Removed.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
```

As I described above, the standard methods of updating the l3 layer through `tlmgr` or TeX Live Utility were not successful. Then I found this post called [Outdated L3 programming layer for expl3.sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586467/outdated-l3-programming-layer-for-expl3-sty?newreg=77043067b31f4fc2abbb2915b5ebc0bc), where I tried

```
tlmgr remove --force l3kernel
tlmgr install l3kernel
```

This also did not work for me, and I got the same `! LaTeX Error: File 'expl3.sty' not found.` error if I did not reinstall `l3kernel`. This also isolated that my issue was related to the `l3kernel` package. Following a comment to that post by Keks Dose lead me to [Mismatched LaTeX support files detected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576918/mismatched-latex-support-files-detected/579759#579759).

At this point I tried the `fmtutil-user --all` suggestion. The [tug.org](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/fmtutil.html) page for the `fmtutil` command says that it will "[r]ebuild and manage TeX fmts and Metafont bases, collectively called 'formats' here". After it ran for a few minutes I tried to render the same file using `xelatex filename.tex` and it worked without issue! Trying to export the same file as a PDF from Jupyter notebook was also successful!

I'm not sure exactly what `fmtutil-user --all` did. I hope by adding all the background to finding the solution someone who is more knowledgeable will be able to piece that together. Thank you all again for your help.

If you try this and still experience an issue, try the modification that the developer Yukai Chou provided for a text file [GitHub Issue #267](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/267). If you're trying to use Jupyter notebook too, you might find my conversation with him helpful. I basically jumped off of the #267 issue and asked where else he suggested to add the control sequence ([GitHub Issue #267](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/268)).

Comment: Good work. I believe it is possible for you to accept your own answer.